# Convert To UTC Time

Tags: c#, datetime, fedex

I am attempting to convert my data to a `DateTime` and `AssumeUniversal` but I am getting an error of

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

This is the format that is being passed in

```
1/10/2017 1:13:00 PM
```

This is my **Track Event** class

```
public partial class TrackEvent {
    private System.DateTime timestampField;
    private bool timestampFieldSpecified;
    private string eventTypeField;
    private string eventDescriptionField;
    private string statusExceptionCodeField;
    private string statusExceptionDescriptionField;
    private Address addressField;
    private string stationIdField;
    private ArrivalLocationType arrivalLocationField;
    private bool arrivalLocationFieldSpecified;

    /// <remarks/>
    public System.DateTime Timestamp {
        get {
            return this.timestampField;
        }
        set {
            this.timestampField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool TimestampSpecified {
        get {
            return this.timestampFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.timestampFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string EventType {
        get {
            return this.eventTypeField;
        }
        set {
            this.eventTypeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string EventDescription {
        get {
            return this.eventDescriptionField;
        }
        set {
            this.eventDescriptionField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string StatusExceptionCode {
        get {
            return this.statusExceptionCodeField;
        }
        set {
            this.statusExceptionCodeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string StatusExceptionDescription {
        get {
            return this.statusExceptionDescriptionField;
        }
        set {
            this.statusExceptionDescriptionField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public Address Address {
        get {
            return this.addressField;
        }
        set {
            this.addressField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string StationId {
        get {
            return this.stationIdField;
        }
        set {
            this.stationIdField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public ArrivalLocationType ArrivalLocation {
        get {
            return this.arrivalLocationField;
        }
        set {
            this.arrivalLocationField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool ArrivalLocationSpecified {
        get {
            return this.arrivalLocationFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.arrivalLocationFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I am attempting to call the conversion:

```
TrackEvent currMax = new TrackEvent();
currMax.Timestamp = DateTime.MinValue;
foreach (TrackEvent trackevent in trackDetail.Events)
{  
 if (trackevent.TimestampSpecified && trackevent.Timestamp > currMax.Timestamp)
{
  currMax = trackevent;                 
  var formats = new[]
  {
    "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt",
    "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mmtt",
    "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt",
    "MM/dd/yyyy h:mmtt",
    "MM/dd/yyyy hhtt",
    "MM/dd/yyyy htt",
    "MM/dd/yyyy h tt",
    "MM/dd/yyyy hh tt",
    "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff",
    "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"
  };
    DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(currMax.Timestamp.ToString(), formats, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal |      System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
    Console.WriteLine(time);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `DateTime.ParseExact` which will look through all your given formats to parse the `string` into `DateTime`.

But the input `datetime` format

```
1/10/2017 1:13:00 PM
```

is having only *one* digit for its month (that is `M/dd` ...) while all your `formats` to parse the input `datetime`with `DateTime.ParseExact` only support *two* digits for day/month (that is: `MM/dd` ...):

```
  var formats = new[]
  {
    "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt",
    "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mmtt",
    "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt",
    "MM/dd/yyyy h:mmtt",
    "MM/dd/yyyy hhtt",
    "MM/dd/yyyy htt",
    "MM/dd/yyyy h tt",
    "MM/dd/yyyy hh tt",
    "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff",
    "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"
  };
```

Note that you use `MM/dd ...` in all you formats

To correct it, you should also include format in `formats` which allow single digit as day/month representation:

```
   var formats = new[]
  {
    "M/d/yyyy hh:mm tt",
    "M/d/yyyy hh:mmtt",
    "M/d/yyyy h:mm tt",
    "M/d/yyyy h:mmtt",
    "M/d/yyyy hhtt",
    "M/d/yyyy htt",
    "M/d/yyyy h tt",
    "M/d/yyyy hh tt",
    "M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff",
    "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"
  };
```

The formats above will support both single digit *and* double digits day and month